# VBA Excel : Choose the hour and the minute from a list

Tags: excel, vba

I want to choose the hour and the minute from a list in my formular and display them in one cell on Excel (Column H)

Hours : ComboBox5

Minutes : ComboBox6

[Formular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCarr.png)

A part of my script :

```
    Sheets("Reservations").Range("A" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("B" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("C" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox3.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("D" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox4.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("E" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox5.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("F" & i).Value = UserForm1.ComboBox4.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("G" & i).Value = DateSerial(UserForm1.ComboBox3.Value, UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value, UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value)

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("H" & i).Value = UserForm1.ComboBox5.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("I" & i).Value = UserForm1.ComboBox7.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("E" & i).NumberFormat = "00 00 00 00 00"

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("H" & i).NumberFormat = "hh\Hmm"

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("I" & i).NumberFormat = "hh\Hmm"

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("G" & i).NumberFormat = "dd mmmm yyyy"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(yourdate, "hh-MM" )

Comment: I didn't understand, you can see a picture of my formular, I added in my question.

Comment: How's all this code related to the question?

Comment: @A.S.H My problem is to put the value of the ComboBox5 and ComboBox6 in one Cell on Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sheets("Reservations").Range("H" & i).Value = _
    Format(TimeSerial(ComboBox5.Value, ComboBox6.Value, 0), "hh:mm")
Sheets("Reservations").Range("I" & i).Value = _
    Format(TimeSerial(ComboBox7.Value, ComboBox8.Value, 0), "hh:mm")
```